# Access a Protected Google Apps Script Web Service via a Native Client (.Net) using OAuth

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-api-client, google-oauth

My .Net Client Application (Winform) allows users to use a Browser Control to Authenticate on Google.   I am able to retrieve the access_token in the response (I follow the instructions  [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)).
Once I get this access_token, how can I use it to 'GET' (or POST) to a protected Google Apps Script.   For instance, if I have a web service URL https://script.google.com/macros/s/XYXYXYXYXYX, that is set to run as the Authenticated User.  Is there a way that I can download the URL using the access_token (either via some special HTTP Header or a .Net Client Oauth Library) acting as the user who authenticated ?   The instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) only show how to access API's protected by google (not Google Apps Scripts).   To be clear, I am not looking to access any Google API's in the Apps Script.  Just some simple XML dynamic XML or JSON documents that are generated by Google Apps Script.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps Script does not support incoming OAuth.